# Flexbox divs resized by image

Tags: css, flexbox

[Example page](http://codepen.io/mastastealth/full/DfcnI)

Firefox/IE10/Opera, upong shrinking the window, maintain the images at the current size, no scaling done at all.

Chrome is the only one that will shrink everything down proportionally as I'd like. I can't tell if Chrome is doing something wrong, or all the other browsers are, or how to go about fixing it.

HTML

```
<section>
<div class="card"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x200" alt="" /></div>
<div class="card"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x200" alt="" /></div>
<div class="card"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x200" alt="" /></div>
<div class="card"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x200" alt="" /></div>
<div class="card"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x200" alt="" /></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  -moz-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.card {
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.card img {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If there's a spec violation, it has nothing to do with Flexbox:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/8a2elgsy

Answer (score -1):

The [flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) has gone through a number of changes over the last few years and various browsers have implemented different versions of the spec.  It's unlikely you'll see much in the way of compatible behaviour at this point.  In particular IE10 and Safari both have mostly working implementations of [an old version of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/).  Firefox has [recently implemented support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=666041) but it is [not enabled by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility).

In particular note that the original design of flexbox, based off the Mozilla CSS extension for XUL, was for distributing *empty space*, not re-sizing elements which already had an innate size.  For this reason it may not be possible to achieve what you're aiming for in all browsers.

If you're still interested in using `flexbox` in a real website check out [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), specifically the tests for [flexbox](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/flexbox.js) and [flexboxlegacy](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/flexboxlegacy.js), you will almost certainly end up writing a set of rules for both cases.

Here are some screenshots in browsers I have installed:

Firefox 21:
[image: Flexbox example in Firefox 21]

Firefox 22:
[image: Flexbox example in Firefox 22]

Chrome 28:
[image: Flexbox example in Chrome 28]

Opera 15:
[image]

Given that the more recent versions of Firefox and Opera look the same as Chrome I would assume that this is the correct behaviour as per the current status of the spec.  The other browsers are therefore doing it wrong.  As for what you can do about it, I would say not much other than what I've already said above - use an alternative approach based on detected support in older browsers.

Comment: This is a non-answer and completely irrelevant because Chrome and Opera both honor the modern flexbox spec (note that `display: -webkit-box` is overwritten by `display: -webkit-flex`).  The draft that IE10 follows is practically the same as the modern spec with different property name/values.

Comment: I don't plan on using Flexbox for anything serious, this is just me messing around with it. I have enabled it for FF, have fallbacks in place for older syntax, but in this case it's a relatively simple usage case and I'm just wondering why Chrome handles the internal <img>'s differently than all the other browsers.

Comment: @Brian In Firefox beta (v22) with Flexbox enabled I see the images scaling as in Chrome

Comment: Gotcha, with Opera moving to Blink then that should work in a future update as well, leaving Safari/IE to play catch up whenever they feel like updating too. Thanks!